# appcompat_v7_15 is missing after creating anew work space, how to import it?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-appcompat

I just created a new work-Space and after importing my projects into the newly created one, I found that some of my projects are marked with a red exclamation mark. I right-clicked on the project and accessed `BuildPath` then I found that `appcompat_v7_15` is missing and marked with red "X". Please let me know how to import the missing library.

Comment: Elpharoah, problem resolved or not?

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar it seems that i stuck in another problem, which is, the project space is empty despite that the workspace folder has the projects?

Comment: Ok, go to file then select import> android (existing android code into workspace)>next >select your workspace and dont tick the(copy project into workspace) means it will be uncheked.

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar upon importing eclipse show an error window says "invalid project description". should make anew question for that?

Comment: I dont know what you are doing wrong there, Do one thing switch to new workspace and do a copy/paste of all projects and then simply attachment to eclipse  will definitely work.

Comment: sure, i know that trick and i asked a question related too that matter before, and the answer was exactly what you have just suggested, but, today it does not work i am trying to solve this since 5 hours, so imagine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your project where you are getting red exclamation mark> Properties > select android > click Add button > select **appcompat_v7** > apply > Ok

Answer (score 0):

go to `project.properties` of the project for which it is showing red. There edit the path to point to library.